# how to develop mac applications using ionic framework

Tags: macos, ionic-framework

i want to create a osx application using ionic framework. Can anybody suggest the possibilities to ceate osx application using ionic framework

Answer (score 0):

Because Ionic operates in a webview (Cordova) as a website and interacts with device through this webview and by using commands that the webview understands, the webview then communicates with the device in native language and relays information back to Ionic. Thinking about osx you would probably need to find a webview capable of doing this. The intricacies I do not know but the principle should follow the same path.